# How to use animation for slowly expanding the container to certain height in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-animation, flutter-animation

I have containers in the listview and whenever one of the containers is seen in the screen more than 75%, the height of the container increases from 100 to 150. 
But how to use animation to expand the container from 100 to 150 in 3 seconds?
I am new to flutter please do help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AnimatedContainer

```dart
AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
            height: expand?150:100,
          )
```

> Ref: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html